# MATLAB: Conversion from char data type to symbolic data type

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, data-conversion

Does anyone know how to make a conversion from char data type to symbolic data type?
I put this:

```
x = 0.49;
n = 22;
roundn(exp(x*49/200),n)
class ans
```

and the answer is:

```
ans =

 0


ans =

char
```

I´m looking for the numeric value. How can I conver char data type to symbolic data type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The output is of the correct class; your problem is in your syntax. Use:

```
class(ans)
```

instead of

```
class ans
```

The first gives you the class of the variable `ans`, the second gives you the class of the string "ans".

Comment: Oh...Thank you! But I´m still having the problem.

Comment: Assuming that by "problem" you mean the answer is still 0, that's because it is 0. `exp(0.049*49/200) = 1.1276`, and `roundn(1.1276, 22) = 0`. Check it out. I have a feeling you're using `roundn` incorrectly... you're rounding to 10^22 here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the output from `roundn(...)` to be a symbolic expression. However, [ROUNDN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/ref/roundn.html) appears to be a function from the [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/), and thus I doubt it will work with symbolic variables.

I think maybe using [VPA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/vpa.html) from the [Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/) is what you want:

```
>> eq = sym('exp(x*49/200)');  %# A symbolic equation
>> x = sym(0.49);              %# A symbolic value
>> n = 22;                     %# Number of digits of precision
>> vpa(subs(eq,'x',x),n)       %# Substitute x and evaluate

ans =

1.127553227831349194548        %# ans is a symbolic value
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
%char
expr = '1+exp(1)';

%sym
x = sym(x);

%number
xval1 = double(x);

%rounded number
xval2 = double(vpa(x, 2));

>> n = 22;
>> expr = exp(x*49/200);
>> res = subs(expr,x,0.49);
res =
    1.1276
>> class(res)
res =
double
>>
```

Comment: Sorry!I don´t looking for that.

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it clear what you are looking for?